# Destroying application from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, locale

In my Application Class I'm registering a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for application Locale changes and it's working fine as I change the locale it works well but I want to close the my Application from where it was created. I have tried to play with context but no success.

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication { 
....
 private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String locale = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
//            Toast.makeText(context, "LOCALE CHANGED to " + locale,
//                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              /* Destroy Here */


        }
    };

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       .........
       ..........
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `System.exit(0);` in your `onReceive` method.

Comment: Application crashes `System.exit(0);` in `onReceive` where as I can alse see the app in the stack

Comment: Share logcat trash for the crash

Comment: there is a `viewpager` in my activity and as i move application to background and changes the locale and bring activity to foreground my app crashes with null pointer exception. All I want is the mechanism to completely remove application from the stack if locale changes. and for this i created a broadcast reciever.